# Create query to return val from B and C for each item in A

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have a database which has a table containing a list of isos (isos.name), a table containing a list of agents with agents.id, and a table containing a list of merchants with merchants.id.

I want to end up with follow result

```
isos.name | Agents    | Merchants
ISO A     |     1     |     7
ISO B     |     2     |     96
```

Both of the following queries work individually, however I don't know how to combine them to return the desired result:

```
SELECT `isos`.`name`, COUNT(agents.id)AS Agents
FROM `isos` 
LEFT JOIN `agents` ON `agents`.`iso_id` = `isos`.`id`
GROUP BY isos.name;
```

This returns:

isos.name | Agents
ISO A     |   1
ISO B     |   2

```
SELECT `isos`.`name`, COUNT(merchants.id)AS Merchants
FROM `isos` 
LEFT JOIN `merchants` ON `merchants`.`iso_id` = `isos`.`id`
GROUP BY isos.name;
```

This returns:

isos.name | Merchants
ISO A     |   7
ISO B     |   96

I would be extremely grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT i.name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM agents a
        WHERE a.iso_id = i.id
       ) AS Agents,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM merchants m
        WHERE m.iso_id = i.id
       ) AS merchants
FROM isos i;
```

This assumes that `name` is unique in `isos`.

The most important reason for using correlated subqueries is that it produces the correct answer.  You are joining along different dimensions (presumably) so the join will produce a Cartesian product for merchants and agents.

A second reason is that with indexes on `agents(iso_id)` and `merchantes(iso_id)`, this should be very fast -- and faster because it avoids aggregating in the outer query.